# trac on windows - authentication

Tags: python, windows, tracking, trac

I wish to use trac (for defect tracking) on windows - as it has nice integration with svn (also on windows).

I got it installed (winpy version) using python 2.7 and was able to get the standalone server up and running - however I have no idea how to configure the logins? As per instructions I created a passwords file with md5 encrypted passwords and then referenced this when I re-ran my standalone server.

Any ideas on how to get this running with authentication?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest ways to manage accounts is by using the [AccountManager plugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/AccountManagerPlugin).  On a fresh Trac install, here's how to set it up:

1. Run the `trac-admin /path/to/projenv permission add anonymous TRAC_ADMIN` command to give yourself admin privileges
2. Install the plugin
3. Create a new admin account graphically
4. Give the admin account `TRAC_ADMIN` permissions
5. Log in using the admin account
6. Revoke the `TRAC_ADMIN` permission from the `anonymous` account
7. Create user accounts, as needed

The website for the plugin lists additional information and examples regarding how to install and configure it.

Comment: Thanks bta but I already tried this, I could navigate to url/trac/admin but couldn't find where to add new users password? Checked documentation but couldn't find anything relevant in there. Any ideas?

Comment: From the Admin tab, look for the "Accounts" category on the left-hand column and click the "Users" option under it.  This will load a page showing a list of all current user accounts, plus an "Add/Edit Account" field that you can use to add new user accounts.  If you aren't seeing any of these, then double-check that your Trac account has all of the "ACCTMGR_*" permissions or is "TRAC_ADMIN".

Comment: No Accounts tab that I can see?

Comment: Follow exactly bta's instruction. Starting with AccountManager 0.5 (current development code) a comprehensive setup wizard will fire for initially, as soon as you hit 'Login'. You need step 1 for even seeing admin panels, its a permission thing.

Answer (score 0):

In case of Trac based on Apache webserver: Another possibility is Apache's SSPI authentication module. Trac reuses all users from the Windows domain then. It's [configured](https://coderanger.net/~coderanger/tracdoc/install/apacheauth.html#sspi-authentication) in http.conf for Trac's .